# Which permissions in my manifest implicitly add <use-feature> to it and avoid download for tablet?

Tags: android, android-manifest, tablet

I have uploaded an application to Google Play Store with the following manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.***.****"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>

    <application>
    ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

But I'm unable to find/download it with a tablet.

I've read the following link in the [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions) but any of my permissions that imply device hardware use seems to be missing on a tablet.

There is no screen support restrictions too.

So I wonder why I can't find the application with a Galaxy Tab A 10.5" (2018) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [GSMARENA](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_tab_a_10_5-9263.php), there are two versions of **Galaxy Tab A 10.5" (2018)** 
one with WI-FI and other with LTE (SIM card).
[image]

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

The `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission requires A **SIM card** , to fix this please add

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
```

Comment: I was expecting of something like that (missing use-feature) but the READ_PHONE_STATE permission is not listed so I wasn't sure. I will give it a try.